# PostgreSQL keep failing password auth in Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

Seems like There's something wrong with `connect` function.

**config.DATABASE_URL** is initialized using environment `export DATABASE_URL=postgres://bustabit:1234@localhost/bustabitdb`

```
function connect(callback) {
    return pg.connect(config.DATABASE_URL, callback);
}


error: password authentication failed for user "bustabit"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/bobbysun/busta/bustabit-gameserver/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:526:11)
```

It's kind of weird that It fails just like in `connect` function when I try to login psql in shell  like:

```
psql -d bustabitdb -U bustabit
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "bustabit"
```

but This one works:

```
psql bustabit -h 127.0.0.1 -d bustabitdb
Password for user bustabit:
psql (9.3.16)bustabitdb=>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this happens? I think I should change `DATABASE_URL` but I'm pretty new to postgreSQL so I have no idea what to change.

UPDATE: upgrading `pg` module to latest version resolves this problem.

Comment: @anoop I don't get what you mean. what should I change in my nodejs code?

Comment: sorry, confused with port & password :)

Comment: Did you try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your URL? `localhost` might be resolving to an IPv6 address, which would match a different [authentication rule](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to your `psql` command.

Comment: @NickBarnes but the error is `peer` - you cant have peer on TCP/IP connection

Comment: @boombamboo "fails just like in connect function" - means with exact same error?

Comment: @VaoTsun: The error in the code using the `localhost` URL is "password", not "peer".

Comment: @NickBarnes ah - missed that line "error: password authentication failed for user "bustabit" - sorry